# AWS Blocking by IP and Mac combo?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh

Several days ago, AWS suddenly started blocking my ability to SSH to ANY of the EC2 servers I've setup across multiple accounts.

When I try to connect I get a message about "client_loop" disconnect and Broken Pipe.

But I can't figure out why. It's not the servers themselves. It has to be Amazon somehow. It's not my SSH keys. It's not my IP address alone. It can't be my mac address alone.

I can VPN to another country and SSH in like I normally would do. This made me think IP Address.

I can connect to my phone's hotspot and then I can SSH as usual. Again, made me think IP Address.

I then decided to try my son's PC (I'm on a mac) and just using the home network like my computer uses, his computer can SSH in. This tells me it's NOT the IP Address alone. So the only thing I can figure is that it must be a combo of IP and Mac address. I can't think of anything else that could be blocking it.

But I have several clients with servers in different AWS data centers and none are configured to block the IP address. But all of them are inaccessible.

I'm very confused as to what to try next. Looking for ideas.

Thanks!

Comment: AWS doesn't know (and cannot know) your MAC address. Most likely it's the problem with your Mac computer. Check the usuals: malware, firewall, antivirus, static routes. Also, try a different SSH client.

Comment: If you increase `ServerAliveInterval` in ~/.ssh/config for this host (or the default), does it help?

Comment: It definitely sounds like an issue on your computer (the Mac?). Make sure you don't have any firewalls configured, and see whether you can SSH into another instance (preferably in the same subnet). Let us know what you find. You can use `ssh -vvv` to turn on debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the OS, check against the audit log of the server itself.

AWS will not be blocking based on Mac Address but its possible that the host OS might have. Outside of that give your home machine a reboot and try again.